# Javafx webview 'outstanding resource locks detected' message

Tags: swing, webview, javafx

I am using javafx webview to load a local html page in a jpanel. Executing the code gives me following message: 
 
Outstanding resource locks detected: D3D Vram Pool: 13,810,710 used (5.1%), 13,810,710 managed (5.1%), 268,435,456 total 
14 total resources being managed 
average resource age is 0.8 frames 
0 resources at maximum supported age (0.000000) 
3 resources marked permanent (21.400000) 
3 resources have had mismatched locks (21.400000) 
3 resources locked (21.400000) 
5 resources contain interesting data (35.700000)

I am new to java and I don't understand why this message is being generated and how it could be resolved (my html page works fine and so does the swing code - gives me the desired result).I tried looking it up online but was unable to find a solution.

Please let me know if any other information is needed.

**Edit:**

I'm trying to develop a video annotation tool. The tags to be attached to the video and their handling is all done in java swing. The video itself is a part of the html page I'm loading in a javafx webview. I've placed a semi-transparent canvas on it which I'm using to register mouse-click events to attach the tags to specific content on the video at a certain time. Below the video tag is another canvas which acts as the timeline (shows attached tags at the appropriate time). That's the basic goal for the code.

Here's the code where I add my jfxpanel:

```
package codingAnnotations;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEvent;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

import javax.swing.JPanel;



@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JFXContainerPanel extends JPanel {

    private final JFXPanel WebViewContainer;
    private final JFXPanel TimeLineContainer;

    public JFXContainerPanel(){

        WebViewContainer = new JFXPanel();
        TimeLineContainer = new JFXPanel();

        add(WebViewContainer);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initFX(WebViewContainer);
            }
        });

    }

    private static void initFX(final JFXPanel fxPanel) {

            Group group = new Group();
            Scene scene = new Scene(group);

            WebView webView = new WebView();

            group.getChildren().add(webView);
            webView.setMinSize(500, 500);
            webView.setMaxSize(800, 600);

            final String html = "res/VideoCanvas.html";
            final java.net.URI uri = java.nio.file.Paths.get(html).toAbsolutePath().toUri();

            System.out.println(uri.toString());

            WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
            webEngine.load(uri.toString());



            webEngine.setOnAlert(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>(){

                @Override
                public void handle(WebEvent<String> arg0) {
                    String value = arg0.toString().substring(10, arg0.toString().length() - 1);
                    System.out.println(value);
                }

            });

            fxPanel.setScene(scene);
        }


}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post the code snippet that you are using ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha - I'm not sure as to what I should post as the code snippet. Should I post the code where I'm loading the jfxpanel? I do know for sure that I started seeing this message once I loaded my local html file in the webview and never when I used something like google.com. Maybe what I'm doing in my html file leads to this? I've edited my post to briefly describe what I'm doing in the html file. Please let me know what other information I can provide. Thanks.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha - I just added the code where I load my jfxpanel. Could it be the way I'm loading the html file in the webview? Thanks.

Comment: I do believe it is a javaFx bug. Could you post your VideoCanvas.html code?